# Can't create folder in internal storage

Tags: java, android, internal-storage

Well, I'm trying to create a folder in my internal storage.
I have watched some tutorial but it's not working at all.

```
        
private void createDir() {
String folderName;


        folderName = "myFolder";
        File file =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folderName);
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.mkdir();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Folder already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

This is my method to create the new directory.
When I launch it, I receive the Toast "Successful" all the time.
But the directory is never created.

Just below the code for the permissions.

```
                    if(!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)){
                        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG,Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS};
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),permissions,1);
                    }else{
                        lay_dataset1=view.findViewById(R.id.lay_dataset1); 
                        messagePerm();
                    }
```

**Here my manifest :**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Can someone explain what is happening :)

EDIT :

```
 private void copyAssets() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getContext().getAssets();

        String[] files = null;
        try {
            files = assetManager.list("");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
        }
        for(String filename : files) {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                in = assetManager.open(filename);
                File outFile = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).getParent().replace("files","myfolder"), filename);
                out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

I tried this, I was able to move files that were in my "asset" folder at the same level as the "files" directory so why shouldn't I have the right to create a folder in this same location ?

Comment: From the Android SDK's standpoint, that is external storage, not internal storage. You do not have write access to that directory on Android 11 and higher. Please do something else, such as use `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context` (no permissions needed!).

Comment: @CommonsWare
`File file =  new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir("MyFirstFolder"), folderName)`
If I do this, my folder "MyFirstFolder" is created into a folder named "files" and I don't want this.
I want a new folder as the same level of the folder named "files".
Sorry I'm a beginner in Android.

Comment: Then use the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`) and allow the user to choose where on the user's device (or in the user's cloud storage) your app should store the user's content. "I want a new folder as the same level of the folder named "files"" -- that is not an option, sorry. If you pass `null` to `getExternalFilesDir()`, `folderName` will go inside of `files`.

Comment: File file = new File((getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null)).getParentFile(), "MyFirstFolder/" +folderName)

Comment: `I receive the Toast "Successful" all the time.` Of course as that directory does not exist and you are not checking return value of mkdir. `if(!file.exists()) if (!file.mkdir()) return;`. Add your Toasts at the right places.

Comment: Good try @blackapps but it's still not working.
No one is created :(

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, I can't create folder in this location /internal_storage/Android/data/com.my.app.test/, write ?
But, @CommonsWare, can I create one before it ? Maybe on /internal_storage/Android/ ?

Comment: "I can't create folder in this location /internal_storage/Android/data/com.my.app.test/" -- AFAIK, that is correct. "can I create one before it ? Maybe on /internal_storage/Android/ ?" -- definitely not.

Comment: Thanks so much @CommonsWare, I just edited my post above for one last question. :)

Comment: "I was able to move files that were in my "asset" folder at the same level as the "files" directory" -- AFAIK, that is not documented as supported. As a result, your results may vary by device or by OS version.

Comment: @CommonsWare well, this is not a good news :( but thanks, I'm still searching and if I find something I will post it here.

Comment: `I can't create folder in this location /internal_storage/Android/data/com.my.app.test/,` If you mean: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app.test/` Then yes you can! And i showed you how to do that.

Comment: @blackapps yeah ! show me how to do that please

Comment: I did already. See comment #4. Mahmoud saw it. Why didnt you?

Comment: @blackapps Yeah, sorry :( u are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first time you run your application, the app external storage directory
at `Android/data/<package.name>/files` is not created until you call this method `getExternalFilesDir(null)` **Twice**.

So try this code..

```
//Essential for creating the external storage directory for the first launch
getExternalFilesDir(null); 

/*
 output->> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package.name>/files 
*/
Log.i("HINT",getExternalFilesDir("").getAbsolutePath());


//Or create your custom folder
File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getParent(),"myfolder");
//make it as it is not exists
outFile.mkdirs();

/*
 output->> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package.name>/myfolder
*/
Log.i("HINT",outFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude @Mahmoud Aly ! I have finally my folder at the same level of files !!